# Is there any method to analysis the variation of chemical species removing the meteorology condition

Tags: atmosphere, atmospheric-chemistry

Here is my question. The concentration of atmospheric species is decided by three major components:

- The source related to natural or anthropology activities.
- The chemical pathway of the formation and removal of this species.
- The diffusion and advection of the species with the atmospheric motion.

To analysis the temporal pattern of one species, e.g, the formation of O3,isolating the chemical reaction as an independent part. I want to eliminate the wind factors (including the wind direction and speed).

Comment: I think you are talking about a chemical box model.  Though you missed deposition on your list.  See http://acmg.seas.harvard.edu/people/faculty/djj/book/bookchap3.html

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Even with a chemical box model, you still need to determine the amount of radiation for photolysis, which is modulated by cloud cover. I guess you can put climatological values into the model, but I wouldn't know where to get that information.